# GitHub: Непонятная идентификация юзера во время push

Tags: git, github

Пытаюсь разместить на GitHub файлы (push), репозиторий там уже создан и склонирован на локальный. Но git выдаёт ошибку:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
ERROR: Permission to [repo_name] denied to [user_name]
```

Непонятно, почему оно считает юзером в данном случае [user_name]. Это имя есть у меня на локальном компьютере, но для данного проекта я явно указал другое [right_user_name].
Выбрал директорию проекта:

```
cd project_directory
```

Указал и локальное имя:

```
git config user.name [right_user_name]
```

И глобальное (после того, как предыдущая процедура не помогла):

```
git config --global user.name [right_user_name]
```

Проверил имя юзера для проекта:

```
git config user.name
```

Показало то, что надо, т.е. [right_user_name]

Тем не менее, при выполнении push происходит то же, что и раньше - оно выдаёт всё то же сообщение об ошибке.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тот `user.name` вообще не при чём, он может быть любым. У вас должен быть сгенерирован ключ для ssh, и его публичная часть должна быть загружена в ваш профиль.

Кроме того, Вы реально должны иметь доступ к репозиторию (устанавливается через веб-интерфейс github).

Comment: Дело в том, что SSH-ключ у меня там есть. Когда я пытаюсь выполнить push, оно сначала долго думает, потом запрашивает у меня логин и пароль. Непонятно, почему, если ключ есть? И после того, как я ввожу свои данные оно мне не даёт доступ. Было бы здорово услышать предположение о причинах этого.

Comment: Вот дополнение:
Когда я выполняю команду $ ssh -T git@github.com (как написано в help на github) оно мне сообщает:
Hi serge-serg! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Это что может значить?

Comment: Sorry, с предыдущим разобрался. Однако далее, сделав всё, что рекомендует github (дошёл до сюда: help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey), и выполнив команду ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (ключи совпали), я получил всё то же сообщение: "fatal: Authentication failed" ... :(

Comment: Используйте ссылку до репозитория вида

    git@github.com:user/repo.git

а не

    https://github.com/user/repo.git